# Hide/Show field on Sharepoint 2019 edit form

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-actions, powerapp, 2019, hide-elements

If there is any posibility to add javascript to Sharepoint list edit form? I would like to hide/show field on form if other field has or hasn’t value. I tried use Power Apps but it isn’t working in real time (you have to save element end open it again to see that field was hidden). Have you any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using *Javascript*.
Please try the below format.

***Note:** I have tested this in SharePoint 2016 Standard Edition.*

---

> $(document).ready(function() {
>  decideFunc();*// to hide or show for new form*
>     *//the below code used for on change event of the
> text. Here am using input type text column as
> //Base Column.*
> $('input[id*="BaseOnColumnID"]').on('input',function(e){
> decideFunc();
>  })
>  });
>
> > function decideFunc(){
> > if($('input[id*="BaseOnColumnID"]').val().trim().toLowerCase()!="value")
> > {
> > hideColumn();
> > }
> > else
> > {
> > showColumn();
> > }
> > }*//decideFunc ends*
> >
> > function hideColumn(){
> > $('input[id*="ColumnID"]').closest("tr").hide();
> > $('input[id*="ColumnID"]').val("");//clear the value while hide
> > }*//hideColumn ends*
> >
> > function showColumn(){
> > $('input[id*="ColumnID"]').closest("tr").show();
> > if(!$('input[id*="ColumnID"]' ).val().trim().length){
> > $('input[id*="ColumnID"]').val("");}
> >  }//showColumn ends

Comment: How you applied this script? Using InfoPath or other solution?

Comment: Add the "Content Editor Webpart" by editing the list form. We can put the JS URL in that "Content Editor Webpart". Sorry i didn't have the  the real-time experience in SharePoint 2019 Online. As per my research knowledge, You should enable the "Classic List Experience" under the "List Settings=> Advanced Settings", to edit the list forms.

Comment: Unfortunetly, I think that there is no option like that with new SP2019 :(